# How do i dynamically add column in dataframe if list of variable increases

Tags: r

How to add column dynamically in dataframe if list of variable increases. My dataframe:

```
ID   Value                                 
1    list(F="20",B="rt")                
2    list(F="20",B="rt",`H'="ty")       
3    list(F="20",B="rt")                
4    list(F="20")
```

Desired output:

```
ID    Value                           F   B   H    
1     list(F="20",B="rt")             20  rt  NA   
2     list(F="20",B="rt",H="ty")      20  rt  ty   
3     list(F="20",B="rt")             20  rt  NA   
4     list(F="20")                    20  NA  NA  




structure(list(Billing = list(NULL, structure
(list(`EUcust#` = "3",`Cust#` = "5", Com = "I", `Com#` = "6", Add = "Y"), .Names
 = c("EUcust#",
"Cust#", "Com", "Com#", "Add"), class 
= "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names 
= "Billing", 
row.names = 8:9, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can u show the expected output for the dput example

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
     bind_cols(., map_df(.$Value, ~do.call(cbind.data.frame, .)))
#  ID      Value  F    B    H
#1  1     20, rt 20   rt <NA>
#2  2 20, rt, ty 20   rt   ty
#3  3     20, rt 20   rt <NA>
#4  4         20 20 <NA> <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Value = structure(list(structure(list(
F = "20", B = "rt"), .Names = c("F", "B")), structure(list(
F = "20", B = "rt", H = "ty"), .Names = c("F", "B", "H")), 
structure(list(F = "20", B = "rt"), .Names = c("F", "B")), 
structure(list(F = "20"), .Names = "F")), class = "AsIs")), 
.Names = c("ID", 
"Value"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for response sir, As per above data frame value it's working fine.But if  row value is null, i'm getting    Error in do.call(cbind.data.frame, .) : second argument must be a list . How can I solve this ERROR sir...

Comment: @udya In that case, you can add a condition i.e. `if(is.null) NA else (.)`

Comment: @udya Could you please update your post with the `dput` output of a small example that show the problem and also the expected output so as to check the structure of your data

Comment: @udya Just get the output of dput and copy/paste in your post by editing

Comment: structure(list(Billing = list(NULL, structure(list(`EUcust#` = "3", 
    ` Cust#` = "5", `Com` = "I", 
    `Com#` = "6", `Add` = "Y"), .Names = c("EUcust#", 
"Cust#", "Com", "Com#", "Add"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(`EUcust#` = "6", 
    `Cust#` = "4", `Com` = "I", 
    `Com#` = "4", `Add` = "Y"), .Names = c("EU cust#", 
"Cust#", "Com", "Com#", "Add"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = "Billing", row.names = 8:10, class = "data.frame")

Comment: @udya For some reason the output is not working for me.  Can u update it in your post by `edit`ing.

Comment: structure(list(Billing = list(NULL, structure(list(`EUcust#` = "3", 
    ` Cust#` = "5", `Com` = "I", 
    `Com#` = "6", `Add` = "Y"), .Names = c("EUcust#", 
"Cust#", "Com", "Com#", "Add"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(`EUcust#` = "6", 
    `Cust#` = "4", `Com` = "I", 
    `Com#` = "4", `Add` = "Y"), .Names = c("EU cust#", 
"Cust#", "Com", "Com#", "Add"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = "Billing", row.names = 8:10, class = "data.frame")

Comment: @uday Please update in your post as in the comments some characters are getting distorted

Comment: <table> structure(list(Billing = list(NULL, structure(list(`EUcust#` = "3", 
  <tr><td>  `Cust#` = "5", Com = "I", `Com#` = "6", Add = "Y"), .Names = c("EUcust#", </td></tr>
 <tr><td>"Cust#", "Com", "Com#", "Add"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = "Billing", row.names = 8:9, class = "data.frame") </td></tr></table>

Comment: Alignment is not working fine for above code, please copy and past code into notepad and save .html. it will open proper alignment sir....

Comment: @udya Sorry, it is difficult to get the correct formatting from the comment.  Could you please update your post by using the `edit` button

Comment: sir ..I have added editable code in top of my post ,please find and revert me.